# windows cmd with too long prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

When I go to a deep directory in MS Windows cmd, the prompt is too long since it show the full name of the working directory.

How to make it hide the directory name or at least part of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`prompt $g` will replace the long path with a beautiful

```
>
```

You can also customize it as you wish, type `prompt /?` for help.

Comment: `prompt` will return the prompt back to it's normal state after you've changed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

@Revolter's answer is the cleanest. You can also use the `subst` command to associate a path with a drive letter. For example, `subst x: .` will associate the `x:` drive with the working directory. Next, enter `x:` to switch to your 'new' working directory. This helps tidy up the command prompt. `subst x: /d` will delete the association. `subst` by itself will show all your pairings.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx). It shows how to get a more sensible dos prompt.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterPROMPTForCMDEXEOrCoolPromptEnvironmentVariablesAndANiceTransparentMultiprompt.aspx